# Initializing pb with Input radio in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, radio-button

I Have several categories (behavior ...) and one category has several criteria (communication ...) :

```
{ 
    "behavior": [ "communication", "autonomy", "creativity" ],
    ... 
}
```

I want to create one radios group for each criterion.
So i use two nested loops (ng-repeat) to create all radio button.

```
<input type="radio" name="{{key}}_{{item}}" value="0" data-ng-model="record[key][item]" /> good
```

See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/asicfr/th0znday/).

I try to initialized all radio button but without success.
My three buttons should be checked, but are not.

Is it the same problem than : 
[Arrays of strings not being handled properly within ng-repeat](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1267)

I don't understand ...

Comment: do you really need name attribute? It works withot it http://jsfiddle.net/th0znday/39/ Do you really concern about angular form ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution, you can not have a single form in two `ng-repeat` you need to use two different form for two `ng-repeat`, one would be `innerForm` and the other one would be `outerForm`, & then there would n number of `innerForm` inside `outerForm`.

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div data-ng-repeat="(key, array) in list">{{ key }} :
        <ng-form name="outerForm">
            <div data-ng-repeat="item in array">{{ item }} :
                <ng-form name="innerForm">
                    <input type="radio" name="radioInput" value="0" 
                    data-ng-model="record[$parent.key][item]" />good
                    <input type="radio" name="radioInput" value="1" 
                    data-ng-model="record[$parent.key][item]" />bad
                </ng-form>
            </div>
        </ng-form>
    </div>
    <hr/>all : {{ record | json }}
</div>
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/th0znday/41/)